# cant get image size and type using the jQuery File Upload plugin, how to?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, jquery-file-upload, image-upload

i am using the [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) jquery plugin to upload some files
i am uploading the pictures from one domain (client side) to another one (server side) through an api.

the image seems to upload fine int he tmp directory on the server side but the `$_FILE` var doesn't contain the image type or size

```
array (size=1)
  'files' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
      'type' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => null
      'tmp_name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '/tmp/phpXyHG5T' (length=14)
      'error' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 0
      'size' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => null
```

the js is simple

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url : 'http://server_side.com/requests/index/image-upload/',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('#upload_button')
                .click(function () {
                    data.context = $('#upload_button').text('Uploading...');
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

the php side

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);

// initialize the upload
$uploadHandler = new Api_Model_UploadHandler();
$uploadHandler->initialize();
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out. 
I'm using Zend Framework.

the issue is that the `$_FILE` looses the `size` and `type` if you ask for it after the `Api_Model_UploadHandler` initialization because the `tmp` image gets removed.

so by asking for the image before seems to work ok.

no need to check if the file exists

```
public function imageUploadAction()
{
    // in case some other crap goes wrong on the website, i want a clean json response
    error_reporting(0);

    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);

    // get the request
    $request   = $this->getRequest();
    // get other params if you sent any

    $fileName = !empty($_FILES) ? $_FILES["files"]["name"][0] : '_';

    if (file_exists('tmp/' . $fileName)) {

        $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();

        if (is_null($files)) {
            $files = $upload->getFileInfo();
        }

                // ... do a regular zend image upload
    }

    // initialize the upload
    $uploadHandler = new Api_Model_UploadHandler();
    $uploadHandler->initialize();

    return json_encode(array());
}
```